# Creating recursive tree function in R: how to make list of the calculations in each node?

Tags: r, list, function, recursion, tree

I wrote a function  which takes a vector (for example x=1:100) and in each step it divides the vector into two sub-vector(x<50 and x>50) it calculate in each sub-vector the min and max and it print them
but I can't allocate a list to the obtained informations in each step!

```
  test<-function(x,p,l=list()){

  print('____________________________')

  if(length(x)>2 & p<4){

  xg<-x[x<(min(x)+max(x))/2]
  xd<-x[x>(min(x)+max(x))/2]
  p=p+1 
  d<-list(xg,xd)

  for(j in 1:length(d)){
    print(paste(p,"------>",p-1))
    print(paste(min(x),max(x)))
    l<-test(d[[j]],p,l)
    }
  }
   return(l)
}

result<-test(1:50,0,l=list())
```

As we see, the result won't give me the entire calculation! You may have a solution?

Comment: What do you get as output versus what do you want as output?

Comment: I've got just the brunches in the screen and I can not access to them. for example I wannat see the results of the third left node. I can have the results of each step in a list, it will be good

Comment: here the "result" gives me just the last loop!

Comment: Also I don't know how to add a counter to this function whi gives me the number of operation